# Getting '' ValueError("x and y must be the same size") " when trying to scatter two arrays in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Here, I'm trying to plot two arrays **arrX** and **arrY** in matplotlib but I'm getting an error which is **"x and y must be same size"**. I've also tried to convert the **arrY** into two dimensional array but it also showing me the same error. How to to solve this issue and what is the reason?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrX = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
arrY = [7,8,9]

plt.scatter(arrX, arrY, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could try `plt.scatter(arrX, np.repeat(arrY, 2))` to have the same number of values in both arrays.

Comment: What result would you expect when the number of x coordinates is different from the number of y corrdinates? Where should the points be plotted?